# Scala how to define an ordering for Rationals

Tags: algorithm, scala, typeclass

I have to implement compareRationals as something like

```
(a, b) => {

   the body goes here
}
```

to compare to fractions, transform them so they both have the same denominator, then order the two results by their numerator to make sure they have the same denominator, need to find out the Least Common Denominator so my code works for println(insertionSort2(List(rationals))) and currently works for all the println statements besides that. I really need help to define compareRationals so println(insertionSort2(List(rationals))) shouldBe List(fourth, third, half)

```
Object {
     def insertionSort2[A](xs: List[A])(implicit ord: Ordering[A]): List[A] = {
        def insert2(y: A, ys: List[A]): List[A] =
          ys match {
            case List() => y :: List()
            case z :: zs =>
              if (ord.lt(y, z)) y :: z :: zs
              else z :: insert2(y, zs)
          }
    
        xs match {
          case List() => List()
          case y :: ys => insert2(y, insertionSort2(ys))
        }
      }
      class Rational(x: Int, y: Int) {
    
        private def gcd(a: Int, b: Int): Int = if (b == 0) a else gcd(b, a % b)
        private val g = gcd(x, y)
    
        lazy val numer: Int = x / g
        lazy val denom: Int = y / g
      }
      val compareRationals: (Rational, Rational) => Int =
    
    
      implicit val rationalOrder: Ordering[Rational] =
        new Ordering[Rational] {
          def compare(x: Rational, y: Rational): Int = compareRationals(x, y)
        }
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val half = new Rational(1, 2)
        val third = new Rational(1, 3)
        val fourth = new Rational(1, 4)
        val rationals = List(third, half, fourth)
        println(insertionSort2(List(4,2,9,5,8))(Ordering.Int))
        println(insertionSort2(List(4,2,9,5,8)))
        println(insertionSort2(List(rationals)))
      }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is all you need.

```
val compareRationals: (Rational, Rational) => Int =
  (x,y) => x.numer * y.denom - y.numer * x.denom
```

Comment: ok i tried and am getting an error No implicit Ordering defined for List[Examples.Rational].
    println(insertionSort2(List(rationals)))

Comment: Variable `rationals` is already a `List` so `List(rationals)` is pretty obviously not what you want.

Comment: oh i think ure right and ok so now i get `List(Examples$Rational@1fbc7afb, Examples$Rational@45c8e616, Examples$Rational@4cdbe50f)` which isn't what i want it's supposed to be List(fourth, third, half)

Comment: The `Rational` class lacks a nice `toString` method. The easiest way to get that is to simple make it a `case class`.

Comment: @randomvalue that is probably what you want, they won't print the variable name nor have you implemented a pretty `toString` but if you compare it with that list you probably will get a `true`

Comment: @jwvh ok now i'm confused. The List contains rationals and it's printing the memory addresses. Making it a case class and you have to add pattern matching?

Comment: a toString will make it so the variable names appear to show List(fourth, third, half)?

Comment: ok so i simply added case and that worked but i have no idea why???

Comment: It worked because a `case class` is basically a regular `class` with a few enhancements. One of those enhancements is a better `toString` method.

Comment: @jwvh to follow up, after simply adding case the output is List(Rational(1,4), Rational(1,3), Rational(1,2)) and would there be a way to make it so it specifically prints the variable names, so it would show up as List(fourth, third, half)?

Comment: OK, I think the best way to do that would be to add a `name` parameter to the `Rational` class and rewrite its `toString` method to use the `name` value.

Comment: @jwvh I'm really confused because my variables are declared in the main method, and I'm overthinking it. How can rewriting toString make the left-hand side variable names appear as it's equal to the right-hand side and would you show what that would look like?

Comment: Study [this Scastie session](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/VjGMCBrnQdqcDSbWQxFwMQ).